# Front derailleur adjustment

Tags: maintenance, derailleur, front

I need some advice on properly adjusting the front derailleur (shimano -tourney) of my bike.

I did watch youtube videos and stuff on the internet but was not able to adjust it properly.

When I attach the wire to the derailleur, either derailleur becomes too tight or too loose, making the gear dysfunctional. Though I tried to fine tune through the two screws, I was unsuccessful.

Any video or any recommendation is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: First leave the cable slack.  Depending on type, the derailer will be all the way in or all the way out.  Adjust the limit screw that comes into play so that the derailer centers over the appropriate ring.  Pull the cable tight.  Adjust the limit screw for the other side.  Finally, adjust the cable so the shifter moves between the two ends and, if a triple, centers over the middle ring.

Comment: I think http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/front-derailleur-adjustments is a pretty good tutorial.

Comment: if you're still having trouble, take it to a shop

Comment: PeteH This is what I am gonna do today :)

Comment: Hope it went ok. As with most things bike, these things come with experience. Adjusting your front derailleur is not massively difficult, if you know how, but in my experience it is a three-handed job. So it can be fiddly.

Comment: Didn't get chance to visit bike shop yet. Wanna try one more attempt to adjust front derailleur myself. I observe one peculiar phenomena in my 3 speed shimano gear system. When the gear-lever goes from 1 to 3, the wire is pulled towards the gear lever ( i-e away from front derailleur). As a result of this, the derailleur moves from smaller disk towards bigger disk, which seems to me an inverse effect. Should not it go from bigger disk to smaller disk when gear lever goes from 1 to 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The small chain ring is considered the first gear, so it goes 1-2-3. The derailleur spring pulls the derailleur always towards the smallest chain ring, which makes sense if the cable snaps during a ride: you could still get home without having to walk your bike on hilly terrain. If it was always on the big chain ring, you would need some serious legs depending on your local hills.

Did you ever check a Shimano manual regarding the front derailleur adjustment? They explain very well what you have to do in detailed steps. But if you can't get it right using the mentioned Park Tool tutorial, i would really recommend visiting the LBS.

What i am missing in the Park Tool tutorial is the step where you have to loosen the inner wire. This should be "Step 0". The wire has to be loosened while adjusting height or rotation of the derailleur.